# Regex match entire string while grouping

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to match a currency string that may or may not be suffixed with one of K, M, or Bn, and group them into two parts

Valid matches:

```
500 K       // Expected grouping: ["500", "K"]
900,000     // ["900,000", ""]
2.3 Bn      // ["2.3", "Bn"]
800M        // ["800", "M"]
```

ps: I know the matches first item in match output array is the entire match string, the above expected grouping in only an example

The Regex I've got so far is this:

```
/\b([-\d\,\.]+)\s?([M|Bn|K]?)\b/i
```

When I match it with a normal string, it does OK.

```
"898734 K".match(/\b([-\d\,\.]+)\s?([M|Bn|K]?)\b/i)
=> ["898734 K", "898734", "K"] // output

"500,000".match(/\b([-\d\,\.]+)\s?([M|Bn|K]?)\b/i)
=> ["500,000", "500,000", ""]
```

Trouble is, it also matches space in there

```
"89 8734 K".match(/\b([-\d\,\.]+)\s?([M|Bn|K]?)\b/i)
=> ["89 ", "89", ""]
```

And I'm not sure why. So I thought I'd add `/g` option in there to match entire string, but now it doesn't group the matches.

```
"898734 K".match(/\b([-\d\,\.]+)\s?([M|Bn|K]?)\b/gi)
=> ["898734 K"]
```

What change do I need to make to get the regex behave as expected?

Comment: what should be the result for `"1 89 8734 K"`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - no match would be ideal

Comment: you're using word boundaries (\b) because this occurs mixed with other text? or are isolated lines?

Comment: @alebianco it's an isolated text, word boundaries not important / needed

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different regular expression, which looks for some numbers, a comma or dot and some other numbers as well, some whitepspace and the wanted letters.

```js
var array = ['500 K', '900,000', '2.3 Bn', '800M'],
    regex = /(\d+[.,]?\d*)\s*(K|Bn|M|$)/
    
array.forEach(function (a) {
    var m = a.match(regex);
    if (m) {
        m.shift();
        console.log(m);
    }    
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem and want to use a regex to solve the problem. Now you have two problems...

Joke aside, I think you can achieve what you want to do without any regex:

```
"".join([c for i, c in enumerate(itertools.takewhile(lambda c: c.isdigit() or c in ',.', s))]), s[i+1:]
```

I tried this with `s="560 K"`, `s="900,000"`, etc and it seems to work.